# Is an ICC warrant sufficient to override diplomatic immunity in signatory nations?

Tags: international-law, diplomatic-immunity, international-criminal-court

As per [recent news](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/3/17/icc-issues-arrest-warrant-for-russias-putin-over-ukraine-crimes):

> The International Criminal Court (ICC) has issued an arrest warrant
> for Russian President Vladimir Putin over alleged war crimes in
> Ukraine, a move dismissed by Moscow as meaningless.
>
> The Hague-based court said in a statement on Friday the warrant was
> issued over Putin’s suspected involvement in the unlawful deportation
> and transfer of children from occupied areas of Ukraine to Russia.

In theory, each Member state is obliged to execute the arrest warrant. But at the same time, if Putin were to visit any of the signatory states, he's all but guaranteed to do so as a foreign official covered by diplomatic immunity. Which rule is supposed to take precedence in this case - the need to provide diplomatic immunity or the need to execute the arrest warrant?

If diplomatic immunity takes precedence, why is it claimed that Putin's travels will be restricted by the ICC warrant, at least while he's still President?

Comment: If a member state arrests a world leader over a warrant what would happen to their leaders/officials when they visit other countries? It might legally override diplomatic immunity but that doesn't mean a country will take action over it. Not to mention if a leader does travel to another country it isn't just the host country that could take action to arrest the leader in question and while it might not be technically legal would they get released because of that?

Comment: @JoeW: Well, one could make the argument that that member had considered that question when deciding whether or not to ratify the Rome Statute - which cedes quite a bit of sovereignty.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't know if the signatory members considered the possibility of having to arrest a sitting head of state when they are visiting at the time of signing it.

Comment: @JoeW: Well, Milosevic was indicted by the special criminal tribunal for former Yugoslavia, [wasn't he](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Tribunal_for_the_former_Yugoslavia)? So, I'm actually pretty sure they considered this.

Comment: @einpoklum He was not indicted by the ICC and those actions happened prior to the ICC being founded. And the indictment means nothing if there is no arrest/trial for them

Comment: @JoeW: He was indicted by a precursor to the ICC, so it stands to reason that the ICC might indict heads of state.

Comment: @einpoklum And as this (and other questions) have been sparked for an arrest warrant being Putin that really isn't the question rather it is would Putin actually be arrested if he visited another country.

Comment: “In theory,” there is no difference between theory and practice, but in practice there is. He may be arrested in _any_ state _X,_ regardless of its status under the Rome, and rendered before the ICC. That's part of the universal jurisdiction. Russia has an option to dispute the arrest with the state _X_ in the ICJ. The dispute will be filed, formally, for use in internal propaganda only. A dictator's chair never gets cold. Someone will take it as a “temporary deputy,” naturally. As if any of the four(!) competing factions of _siloviki_ would want him back, should such a sweet opportunity open!

Comment: @JoeW “would Putin actually be arrested if he visited another country” — That we'll probably never know, because he won't. Unless that another country is Belarus—and even that might not be for too long: the situation there is not yet heating up, but sighs of its starting to warm up are hard to miss.

Comment: @kkm but we already an answer that shows another world leader with an ICC arrest warrant traveling to signatory countries and not getting arrested. I don't see how that can't be used to draw an answer for the current situation.

Comment: @JoeW I understand you want to “to draw an answer for the current situation,” i.e. know the future with certainty, correct? If that's the case, I suggest visiting a fortune teller. All I said that it was very _unlikely_ that he would take the risk. That's until he has no choice, but then not in any official capacity. And, considering he's 70, stiff after trauma and has never been a trained FSB operative, unlike Litvinenko, and held an office job, I *estimate* his chances to make it to a safe haven alive as very low in case of loss of said capacity. Estimate. But I don't know the future, sorry.

Comment: @kkm It isn't just the current situation, as we already have examples provided of other world leaders with an arrest warrant out for them traveling there should be enough information to derive an answer for what would happen if Putin traveled to other countries at this point in time. As the provided example is for a smaller and less powerful country I don't think it is that hard to extrapolate what that would mean for a much larger and more powerful country like Russia.

Comment: Since Putin is the head of state of Russia, he can assert state immunity for actions taken in that role as well as diplomatic immunity. So he may not be liable to arrest in another country even if not covered by diplomatic immunity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the ICC warrant supposed to restrict Putin's travel abroad given that he's in possession of diplomatic immunity?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78764/how-is-the-icc-warrant-supposed-to-restrict-putins-travel-abroad-given-that-he)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The very first warrant of arrest ever issued for a *sitting* Head of State by the ICC applies here.

After the ICC [issued warrant for arrest](https://www.icc-cpi.int/news/icc-issues-warrant-arrest-omar-al-bashir-president-sudan) of **Omar Al Bashir**, President of Sudan, he [made 75 travels¹ abroad](https://nubareports.org/bashir-travels/) to 22 countries, **7 of which are signatories to the ICC**.

So, at least from the point of practical law application, at least seven states have considered the diplomatic immunity above the ICC order.

> *On several occasions, the International Court of Justice², arguably the most authoritative court ruling on matters of international law, [confirmed](https://www.icj-cij.org/files/case-related/136/136-20080604-JUD-01-00-EN.pdf) that heads of state enjoy “full immunity from criminal jurisdiction and inviolability”. This also appears to [protect them](https://www.icj-cij.org/files/case-related/121/121-20020214-JUD-01-00-EN.pdf) “against any act of authority of another state which would hinder him or her in the performance of his or her duties”.* — [The Conversation](https://theconversation.com/why-sudan-wont-hand-over-former-president-al-bashir-to-the-international-criminal-court-117810)

It is not known whether these 7 states have faced any legal consequences of their failure to comply with the decision of the Court they signed to.

---

¹) 2009 to 2016, per the article date
²) The entire article discusses ICC (criminal), while this paragraph refers ICJ (civil). The ICJ (contrary to the ICC) may or may not be relevant here.

Comment: *any legal consequences of their failure to comply with the decision of the Court they signed to* => there are no legal consequences spelled out in the ICC agreement, so the answer is clearly no.

Comment: It probably depends on the country and on the relations towards the warranted persons. Maybe there are also cases where an ICC warrant was sufficient to override diplomatic immunity in a signatory nation.

Comment: I don't like it when respondents condescend the poster for "not doing research". If everyone is expected to answer their own questions without assistance, then this website would not need to exist. The whole point of this place is to match those who do not have enough knowledge with those who do have the relevant knowledge at hand. Also these answers will likely be the first search result for general public years down the line, it is okay to have knowledge differential.

Comment: @QuantumWalnut I removed the first sentence. On the other hand, the fact that there are *not so many* relevant cases makes prior research pretty much trivial, and the OP seems not to object on my remark. Nevertheless, removed.

Comment: "at least seven states have considered the diplomatic immunity above the ICC order" <- Or decided to ignore their obligation on the matter (and those two are no the same thing).

Comment: @einpoklum you're right; I used a more neutral understanding of the fact to avoid any humiliation of these 7 states. If the real reason is what you said (and it gets proven in court), that may trigger a more severe legal consequences for them.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine: I understand, but - "saving face" for those states should not be a consideration when answering here. That is, it's possible that these states have never claimed that immunity trumps the warrant _in principle_, which is what OP asked about.

Comment: @einpoklum the quoted article specifically talks *[…] heads of state enjoy full immunity from […]*. It does not talk about *some states "decided to ignore their obligation"* as you are suggesting. Should you have sources corroborating with your suggestion, please feel free to suggest an edit or, alternatively, submit another answer.

Comment: Sorry, BeBraveBeLikeUkraine; your link 'confirms' nothing useful.

That link leads only to 74 pages of boring and irrelevant detail about how the ICJ says states should deal with each other. It has nothing substantive to do with the ICC.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin thanks, this single paragraph, indeed, talks ICJ while the entire article is about the ICC. I made a note in the answer.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine Sorry. My Comment referred only to 'confirmed' link, which I hoped would be obvious from its using quotation marks.

Your other links I didn't trouble with because your 'confirmed' link lead only to 74 pages of tedious detail about how the ICJ says states should deal with each other. 

What was there useful to do with the ICC?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin thanks for the clarification. I kept the whole quote block intact, the way they present in the original article on 'The Conversation' site, *along with the links within.*

Comment: Note that arresting a sitting head of state that way would only work once.

Answer (score 8):

Yes and No.

While *Article 27* of the Rome Statute does say that even acting heads of state are not immune from prosecution, *Article 98(1)* provides an exception to this rule:

> The Court may not proceed with a request for surrender or assistance which would require the requested State to act inconsistently with its obligations under international law with respect to the State or diplomatic immunity of a person ... of a third State, unless the Court can first obtain the cooperation of that third State for the waiver of the immunity.

(In the context we are discussing, "the requested" state would be the ICC member state and the "third" state Russia).

Apparently this is the [legal loophole that South Africa considered to avoid arresting Putin](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/south-africa-grants-vladimir-putin-other-russian-officials-diplomatic-immunity-for-brics-summit/article66910972.ece) if he arrived for the BRICS summit there. (Note though that ultimately Putin didn't attend the summit personally).

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**

The principle of International Law, which under certain circumstances provide diplomatic immunity, cannot be applied to acts which are condemned as criminal by International Law [(source)](https://www.ejiltalk.org/the-law-of-immunity-and-the-prosecution-of-the-head-of-state-of-the-russian-federation-for-international-crimes-in-the-war-against-ukraine/):

> The IMT was established for the punishment of the major war criminals of the European Axis, i.e. for the trial and punishment of German high officials who perpetrated aggression, war crimes, and crimes against humanity “[in connection](https://www.un.org/en/genocideprevention/documents/atrocity-crimes/Doc.2_Charter%20of%20IMT%201945.pdf)” with the Second World War. At the end of the trial, the IMT issued one of the most important judgments in the history of international law. On the question of immunity, the position of the IMT consisted of the following:
>
> The principle of International Law, which under certain circumstances protects the representatives of a State, *cannot be applied to acts which are condemned as criminal by International Law.* The authors of these acts cannot shelter themselves behind their official position in order to be freed from punishment in appropriate proceedings […]. On the other hand […] he who *violates the laws of war cannot obtain immunity* while acting in pursuance of the authority of the State if the State in authorizing action moves outside its competence under International Law (emphasis added).

Another answer says some such diplomats were not arrested, this  still may not mean that if arrested, they could present this    as a violation of international law. There were protest activities during these visits. It was especially tough for al-Bashir in South Africa where courts and local activists intervened, and the whole situation was quite tense [(source)](https://novayagazeta.eu/articles/2023/03/19/will-putin-ever-stand-trial-in-the-hague-en).

Surely, professional diplomats avoiding confrontation, leave alone the nuclear strike as Dmitry Medvedev now [threatens](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2023/mar/23/russia-ukraine-war-live-bakhmut-offensive-slowing-says-us-thinktank-eu-leaders-gather-for-summit), may first tell in a very polite and subtle way the head of state under warrant that maybe could defer the visit, "it is too rainy now". If this would not work, it would probably be less confrontation by declaring him *persona non grata*. The head of state will miss some meetings and events that may be important.

Comment: Is there any evidence to back this up such as someone with diplomatic immunity getting arrested because of these type of crimes and a warrent?

Comment: That it has not been done before, does not mean it will never be done. A diplomat with ICC arrest warrant does not come on daily basis to have examples very abundant. As for Putin, Germany said it would do.

Comment: I took my liberty to add a relevant quote from the linked article.

Comment: Your right it doesn't come up that often but we also have examples of leaders with an ICC arrest warrant out for them and them traveling to signatory countries without any attempts to arrest them. The other answer to this question shows that it isn't enough to get someone arrested and it gives an example of someone from a much less powerful country not being arrested.

Comment: "which under certain circumstances provide diplomatic immunity" <- Diplomatic immunity predates the current international legal system, and is at most recognized by it rather than relying on it. It relies on age-old customs, and very often on aspects of bilateral relations, formal or informal.

Answer (score -1):

History seems to show that yes, an ICC warrant is sufficient to override diplomatic immunity… partly because the International Criminal Court and Court of Justice are very different things and the tomes cited above apply to civil relations between governments, not to fugitive suspects.

ICC has issued 30-some warrants including several for government ministers and - before Putin - four for heads of state.

Omar Hassan Ahmad al-Bashir head of state of Sudan from 1989 until 2019, was indicted in 2009.

Uhuru Muigai Kenyatta, indicted in 2011, was president of Kenya from 2013 to 2022 but the charges against him stood until 2015.

Koudou Laurent Gbagbo was President of Côte d'Ivoire on his arrest in 2011. He was apparently released in 2019, and acquitted in 2021. Please don’t ask me how that works.

Muammar Muhammad Abu Minyar al-Gaddafi, was still leader of Libya on his indictment in 2011.

Comment: Did any of these leaders get arrested while traveling as head of state?

Comment: Personally, I neither know nor care. Some were arrested…

Of course, international law could see various differences between their being arrested abroad or on their home territory.

Are you suggesting Mr Opposition is going to arrest his own leader on an ICC warrant, when he couldn't do it under his own territory's laws?

Comment: You might not care but it is an important piece of information. If no country is willing to actually arrest a visiting head of state with an ICC arrest warrant out for them does it really matter if it is enough to get around diplomatic immunity?

Comment: Well, Joe, why not do your own research? I merely cited some history…

Comment: You are the one providing the answer and I am asking for some details and supporting evidence for that answer. It is one thing to say that yes an ICC warrant overrides diplomatic/sovereign immunity but does that actually mean anything if no country is actually arresting a sitting head of state because of an ICC warrant?

Comment: @Joe W  Sorry but you are clearly not asking for evidence supporting that Answer. You are clearly going beyond my simple statement of historical fact and Asking about something different. That's your choice but please don't again pretend to be 'asking for some details and supporting evidence…'

Either way, how is Gbagbo irrelevant to you? Is that it, or do you have other quibbles?

Again, Joe, why not do your own research? I merely cited some history…

Comment: I am asking if any of the leaders who you say had arrest warrants issued for them got arrested during their time in office. You are the one providing an answer and it is not up to the people reading it to do more research to be able to understand your answer. If the arrest warrants end up being symbolic because nothing ever comes out of them then it doesn't really matter what people say it means about diplomatic immunity.

Comment: @Joe W 'If the arrest warrants end up being…' being anything you like, please make that either a Comment to the OQ, or an Answer of your own. Either way, that you mind whether anyone was arrested during their time in office might be a reasonable corollary to the OQ but my Answer remains a simple statement of historical fact; hardly open to 'understanding.' If you have trouble 'understanding' you might explain what trouble.

Comment: What is the point of saying that an ICC arrest warrant overrides diplomatic/sovereign immunity if no country is willing to actually arrest a leader who is a target of the arrest warrant because of the diplomatic issues it could cause? Your answer states that they can issue arrest warrants which is already well established by the fact that they issued one for Putin the question remains is would he get arrested if he traveled to a signatory country because it overruled the sovereign immunity he has as the leader of Russia.

Comment: @JoeW How many times do I have to repeat that I Posted a statement of historical, not an opinion that needed 'understanding'?  Please Post your doubts and queries under the Original Question.

Comment: You posted an answer and I asked you for clarification on your answer to include some additional information. You are making a claim that an ICC warrant is enough to override immunity yet there is no evidence of that actually happening and leaders being arrested. No matter how many times the claim is made that it overrides immunity if no one is actually being arrested it isn't true.

Comment: @JoeW Please recognise, you misinterpret what I Posted. That 'History seems to show… an ICC warrant is sufficient…' and the warrants listed for four heads of state remain true, and make no other 'claim'. 

No one being arrested might make the idea those warrants over-ride that immunity untrue only if you showed there were no economic or political reasons but how could you?

Why not Post your own Answer and evidence, or go to Chat? I don't think you're taking this off topic, but how are extended discussions allowed?

Comment: That is why I am asking for clarification in your answer as the question is not asking if they can issue an arrest warrant as it is referencing the one issued for Putin. What it is asking is if that arrest warrant overrides diplomatic/sovereign immunity and if there is no evidence of any countries taking action such as arresting a leader because it I would argue that the arrest warrant doesn't override diplomatic/sovereign immunity.

Comment: @JoeW Look… even the forum thinks this discussion is too extended. Again and I hope finally, if it helps you to forget all about everything I've said please, do just that. If you want to 'argue' that the warrant doesn't override immunity stop simply stating that, and argue it!

To the forum do, please thank Goodness, move this to chat!

Comment: All I am asking you to do is answer my question and state if any leaders have been arrested over an ICC warrant before or simply state that you don't know. Trying to push my question about your answer back on to me isn't the way to address a concern about your question.

Comment: @JoeW I gave you the full list of indictments, arrests and outcomes, so far as the WWW seems to know them. It looks as though Gbagbo, as President of Côte d'Ivoire on his arrest in 2011, might be the only one that suits you. Does that help? Either way, why can you not do your own research and then Post a useful Answer? To the forum do, please thank Goodness, move this to chat!